# -(NSUInteger) numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot is not calling

Tags: core-plot, cppiechart

Hi I am doing `CPTPieChart` for some iPhone application.
I have added the `delegate` and `datasource` of the `cptpiechart` in my `@interface` section.

`-(NSUInteger) numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot` method is not calling..may I know any possible reasons from any one of you...thanx in advance..

Comment: Did you also set the `delegate` and `datasource` properties of the plot?

Comment: This is the code I am using for create pie chart                CPTPieChart *pieChart2 = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
    pieChart2.dataSource = self;
    pieChart2.pieRadius = 100.0f;
    pieChart2.startAngle = M_PI_4;
    pieChart2.sliceDirection = CPTPieDirectionClockwise;
    pieChart2.delegate = self;

Comment: Its done..I have taken one CPTXYGraph and adding this Piechart to that graph. Adding CPTXYGraph to CPTHostingGraphView..I missed to host this CPTXYGraph to CPTHostingGraphView..